# Open new tab in swt browser after button click

Tags: java, browser, swt

I used `SWT` browser. I opened page and there is a `Button` which verify that browser have option to open new browser window. Standard `SWT` browser have problem with it. Above is how button is defined.

```html
<button class="btn btn-action btn-slim size-w-90pct" data-e2e="openDealerBtn" ng-if="igDefaultRowController.account.isPdSupported" ng-class="{'btn-disabled': igDefaultRowController.shouldDisableOpenPlatformButton}" ng-disabled="igDefaultRowController.shouldDisableOpenPlatformButton" ng-click="igDefaultRowController.openDealer()" ig-click-tracking="pureDealBtn-CFD" id="openDealerButton-XQ7JI"> <span class="btn-label" ig-i18n="" key="AccountOverview.openDealer"><span ng-bind-html="value">Open classic platform</span></span> </button>
```

1. [SOLVED!] How to expand `SWT` browser to open more than one tab ?

   - I used `TabFolder` for more tabs.
2. It is possible to catch URL after click on this button and open in new SWT browser tab ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SWT uses one of the browsers that are available on the operating system and embeds the main "view" of the browser (the bit that displays the html) in your application. That does mean, however, that it doesn't come with all the fancy stuff like tabs.

As you already discovered yourself, you can get around this by using a `TabFolder`.

The question now is: how do you know when a tab should be opened. This code (adopted from [Snippet270](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet270.java)) should help you with this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("Main Window");
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
    final Browser browser;
    try
    {
        browser = new Browser(shell, SWT.NONE);
    }
    catch (SWTError e)
    {
        System.out.println("Could not instantiate Browser: " + e.getMessage());
        display.dispose();
        return;
    }
    initialize(display, browser);
    shell.open();
    browser.setUrl("http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_links_target");
    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}

/* register WindowEvent listeners */
static void initialize(final Display display, Browser browser)
{
    browser.addOpenWindowListener(e ->
    {
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setText("New Window");
        shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
        Browser browser1 = new Browser(shell, SWT.NONE);
        initialize(display, browser1);
        e.browser = browser1;
    });
    browser.addVisibilityWindowListener(new VisibilityWindowListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void hide(WindowEvent e)
        {
            Browser browser = (Browser) e.widget;
            Shell shell = browser.getShell();
            shell.setVisible(false);
        }

        @Override
        public void show(WindowEvent e)
        {
            Browser browser = (Browser) e.widget;
            final Shell shell = browser.getShell();
            if (e.location != null) shell.setLocation(e.location);
            if (e.size != null)
            {
                Point size = e.size;
                shell.setSize(shell.computeSize(size.x, size.y));
            }
            shell.open();
        }
    });
    browser.addCloseWindowListener(e ->
    {
        Browser browser1 = (Browser) e.widget;
        Shell shell = browser1.getShell();
        shell.close();
    });
}
```

This will open the link in a new `Shell` with a new `Browser`. You can change this, so it creates a new tab and adds the new browser to the new tab.

---

**EDIT**

Here's a working example using `TabFolder`:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("Main Window");
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    TabFolder tabFolder = new TabFolder(shell, SWT.BORDER);

    addNewBrowser(tabFolder, "<a href='http://www.google.co.uk' target='_blank'>Click here!</a>");

    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}

private static Browser addNewBrowser(TabFolder folder, String html)
{
    TabItem item = new TabItem(folder, SWT.NONE);
    Composite c = new Composite(folder, SWT.NONE);
    item.setControl(c);
    c.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    Browser browser = new Browser(c, SWT.NONE);

    if (html != null)
    {
        browser.setText(html);
        item.setText("Original tab");
    }
    else
    {
        item.setText("New tab");
    }

    browser.addOpenWindowListener(e ->
    {
        e.browser = addNewBrowser(folder, null);
    });
    browser.addVisibilityWindowListener(new VisibilityWindowListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void hide(WindowEvent e)
        {
            Browser browser = (Browser) e.widget;
            Shell shell = browser.getShell();
            shell.setVisible(false);
        }

        @Override
        public void show(WindowEvent e)
        {
            Browser browser = (Browser) e.widget;
            final Shell shell = browser.getShell();
            if (e.location != null) shell.setLocation(e.location);
            if (e.size != null)
            {
                Point size = e.size;
                shell.setSize(shell.computeSize(size.x, size.y));
            }
            shell.open();
        }
    });
    browser.addCloseWindowListener(e ->
    {
        Browser browser1 = (Browser) e.widget;
        Shell shell = browser1.getShell();
        shell.close();
    });

    folder.setSelection(item);

    return browser;
}
```

Comment: Looks great, I will test it and give You an answer.

Comment: I do not test it yet but it is acceptable answer :) Thanks!

Comment: @czArek You don't have to accept the answer before you tested it, I was just curious.

Comment: Can You told me how to catch address from button which redirect to new page ? I want catch address from button and open in my new tab

Comment: I mean that how to get html value from button (after click). I think that I need script to get this

Comment: @czArek Why do you need that? Originally you wanted to open in a new tab, which the answer does.

Comment: In original window I want open page, example "http://google.com" and when I click on button (button inside page) I want create new Tab and load new page there

Comment: @czArek I don't know how to get the URL from the event

Comment: Ok, told me only how to open page in Original tab (not href) - load page by address

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124194/discussion-between-baz-and-czarek).